# Create a list dynamically and store all the values matching with current value in python 3.x

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, indexing, append

I have a text file which has data created dynamically like

```
1000L 00V
2000L -10V
3500L -15V
1250L -05V
1000L -05V
2000L -05V
6000L -10V
1010L 00V
```

and so on...

The numbers before V could vary from `-160 to +160`

I want to create a list (not using dictionary) dynamically and store the values in a list according to the matching numbers before `V`

In this case I want to create sets of list as follows

```
 00 = ["1000", "1010"]
-10 = ["2000", "6000"]
-15 = ["3500"]
-05 = ["1250", "1000", "2000"]
```

Tried code:

```
if name.split()[1] != "":
    gain_value = name.split()[1]
    gain_value = int(gain_value.replace("V", ""))
    if gain_value not in gain_list:
        gain_list.append(gain_value)
        gain_length = len(gain_list)
        print(gain_length)
        g['gain_{0}'.format(gain_length)] = []
        'gain_{0}'.format(gain_length).append(L_value)
    else:
        index_value = gain_list.index(gain_value)
        g[index_value].append(L_value)

for x in range(0, len(gain_list)):
    print(str(gain_list[x]) + "=" + 'gain_{0}'.format(x))
```

But the above code doesn't work as I get an error while appending `'gain_{0}'.format(gain_length).append(L_value)` and I am unsure how to print the list dynamically after its created as mentioned in my required output.

I can't use dictionary for the above method because I want to give the lists dynamically as input to **pygal module** as below:

as I need the output for pygal module as input like :

```
for x in range(0, gain_length):
    bar_chart.x_labels = k_list
    bar_chart.add(str(gain_length[x]),'gain_{0}'.format(x))
```

Here I can add the values only from a list not from a dictionary

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @61612 I have edited my question :) hope its more clear now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
import collections
my_dict = collection.defaultdict(list)
with open('your_file') as f:
    for x in f:
        x = x.strip().split()
        my_dict[x[1][:-1]].append(x[0])
```

output:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, { '00': ["1000", "1010"],
'-10':["2000", "6000"],
'-15': ["3500"],
'-05': ["1250", "1000", "2000"]})
```

for your desired output:

```
for x,y in my_dict.items():
    print "{} = {}".format(x,y)
```

Comment: Is there any possibility use lists for the purpose? as I need to use the output in pygal. It would be better to use a list instead....

Comment: its just a dictionary with key values

Comment: I get an error `AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'split'` as well as the issue is I need a list, because I can use only a list as input in pygal module to create a chart, thats why in my question I have specifically asked for a `list` to be created dynamically I can't add a dict value to pygal module....